# PlayConsole: Setting initial project from command-line

Tags: playframework

I have a play! project with a number of sub-projects which are put together in a Build.scala build definition. So when I run *play* and within the console type *projects*, I get something like this:

```
[my-foo] $ projects
[info] In file:/home/x/my-foo/
[info]   * my-foo
[info]     my-foo-bar
[info]     my-foo-baz
```

Now, I know I can switch to one of my projects using `project my-foo-bar` from the console. But is there a way to switch to a project directly when launching play, especially in combination with e.g. `play compile`? Reason is I would like to compile a specific project e.g. like so:

```
play project my-foo-bar clean compile
```

Cheers, Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, found it. The correct syntax is the same as when using sbt directly. For instance:

```
play "project my-foo-bar" clean compile
```